# Multi programming operating system

Tags: operating-system

Why is Google chrome/Ms Excel a multi programming operating system?
On what basis can we say  Google chrome/Ms Excel is a multi programming operating system?

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome/MS Excel is not an operating system and is in a computer program.

A multiprogramming operating system can run multiple programs concurrently on the same processor.

for eg: Windows can run multiple apps at the same time like chrome, excel etc. Hence Windows is an multiprogramming OS.

Comment: But Windows is a multi tasking operating system.Can windows have both these operating systems?

Comment: Yes since windows fulfil the definition of both types of OS, it is an example of both types of OS. eg: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-multitasking-multithreading-and-multiprocessing/